# problem with submitting form , from fancybox window

Tags: jquery, submit, fancybox

I have this function

```
   jQuery("form#add_cv").submit ( function(){ 
    if (Spry.Widget.Form.validate(this) == true){

            jQuery("#show_rules").fancybox({
                'padding'       : 0,
                'autoScale'     : false,
                'autoDimensions': false,
                'transitionIn'  : 'none',
                'transitionOut' : 'none',
                'width'     : 600,
                'height'        : 450,
                'titlePosition'     : 'inside',
                'scrolling' : 'no'
            }).trigger('click'); 

            jQuery('div#sb_buttons button#cancel_submit').click(function() { 
                $.fancybox.close();
                return false;
            });


            jQuery('div#sb_buttons button#submit_form').click(function() { 
                jQuery("form#add_cv").submit("true");
                $.fancybox.close();
                return true;
            });

        return false;
    }
});
```

On clicking on ok button

```
            jQuery('div#sb_buttons button#submit_form').click(function() { 
                jQuery("form#add_cv").submit("true");
                $.fancybox.close();
                return true;
            });
```

, from fancybox window . Form from actual page is submitting , and fancybox window is closing then the submit function is repeating again , how can i solve the problem ... sorry for this kind of question ... but i don't have idea what to do , and sorry for my English , hope you will understand me :) Thanks

Comment: You English is fine. Better than some we have here.

Comment: @James Wiseman - Upvoted for being hilarious. (Am currently reading code, but thought you should know).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After some good hours of searching , i finally solved the problem , and big thx to Xian for help also.

this is the result :

```
    jQuery("form#add_cv").submit ( function(){ 

    if( typeof( accept ) != 'undefined' ){
        if(accept){ return true }
    }


    if (Spry.Widget.Form.validate(this) == true){

            jQuery("#show_rules").fancybox({
                'padding'       : 0,
                'autoScale'     : false,
                'autoDimensions': false,
                'transitionIn'  : 'none',
                'transitionOut' : 'none',
                'width'     : 600,
                'height'        : 450,
                'titlePosition'     : 'inside',
                'scrolling' : 'no'
            }).trigger('click'); 


            jQuery('div#sb_buttons button#cancel_sb').click(function() { 
                $.fancybox.close();
                return false;
            });

            jQuery('div#sb_buttons button#sb_form').click(function() {
                accept=true;
                $.fancybox.close(); 
                return  true;
            });


         return false;   
    }


});
```

i added this line of code

```
    if( typeof( accept ) != 'undefined' ){
        if(accept){ return true }
    }
```

after clicking the ok button , i declared that accept is true , after form can be submitted  , thanks to all that tried to help me ;)

Answer (score 0):

It appears to me that when you click submit you are telling jQuery to submit the form and close your fancybox. Then assuming your submit button is actually `type=submit`, it's inherent behaviour takes over and it submits the form.

Why don't you try removing the line `jQuery("form#add_cv").submit("true");` from your submit function?

Comment: I removed it , and no reaction , i wasted a lot of time trying a different methods , and no idea , help please